# Dynamically getting the value of an excel cell - cross document

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know it is possible to look up the value of a cell in another Excel document using the following formula:

```
=whole.csv!$A$1
```

But is it possible to add the cell address dynamically?

For example, I am finding the row number of a cell using the following query:

```
=MATCH(A1, whole.csv! $W$2 : $W$1000, 0) + 1
```

What I would like to do is use this row number to access the value of a column in that row. So, if `MATCH()` returned `567`, I would want to look up `=whole.csv!$A$567`.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
=whole.csv!$A$( MATCH(A1, whole.csv! $W$2 : $W$1000, 0) + 1)
```

But Excel informs me that this formula contains an error -> so obviously this is not the right solution.

Does anyone have any good ideas on how this may be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question closed:

I should be using `LOOKUP()`

**So the answer would be:**

```
=LOOKUP(A1, whole.csv! $W$2 : $W$1000, whole.csv! $A$2 : $A$1000)
```

Thanks to everyone who took a look.